# Is a creature immune to the prone condition also immune to being incapacitated by the Tasha's Hideous Laughter spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, immunities

The [*Tasha's hideous laughter*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hideous-laughter) spell description states:

> A creature of your choice that you can see within range perceives everything as hilariously funny and falls into fits of laughter if this spell affects it. The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or fall prone, becoming incapacitated and unable to stand up for the duration.

If a creature is immune to the [prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Prone) condition, can it still become [incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) by the spell if it fails its Wisdom save ?

The text seems to indicate that the creature becomes incapacitated after falling prone, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 15):

## They are inflicted with the incapacitated condition.

Linguistically, this is troublesome, because "becoming incapacitated and unable to stand up for the duration" appears to be a descriptor of "prone", which it is not. "Unable to stand up for the duration" appears to be a more specific ruling of the prone condition (PHB. 292), contradicting the first point:

> A prone creature's only movement option is to crawl, unless it stands up and thereby ends the condition.

**However, because it is not a descriptor, the only other option is that the save forces the target to fall prone once and inflicts "incapacitated and unable to stand up" for the duration.**

It is interesting that this wording would normally prolong the prone condition  by removing the option that that creature has to remove the prone condition from themselves, but not by forcing a creature to stay inflicted with the "prone" condition.

This means that while the creature with immunity to the prone condition and targeted by *Tasha's hideous laughter* does not become prone, it is affected by the rest, and therefore cannot take the action (lowercase a) "stand up," and is also incapacitated (condition).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80732/discussion-on-answer-by-blake-steel-is-a-creature-immune-to-the-prone-condition).